# Module not found: Can't resolve '@babel/runtime/core-js/array/from'

Tags: reactjs

I am new to `react` and I have this problem when trying to use `react-bootstrap`.

I've installed `react-bootstrap`, `reactstrap` and `react-bootstrap-select`, and the problem is that when I try to import something from `react-bootstrap` I get this error:

> ./node_modules/react-bootstrap/es/DropdownMenu.js Module not found:
>   Can't resolve '@babel/runtime/core-js/array/from' in
>   'C:\webprojects\react\mytest-app\node_modules\react-bootstrap\es'

I removed the line calling this script and I got another similar error, but that mentions another script.

I have searched in many placed on the web and installed `babel-runtime` and I tried `npm install` but nothing seems to work. If I go to the mentioned folder I find these scripts. I don't really know what to do or what is the exact problem here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you post the content of your `package.json` please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a recently introduced bug you are hitting, making the current 0.32.2 version of react-bootstrap incompatible with the babel version used:

https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/3231

We temporarily fixed the react-bootstrap version in package.json to 0.32.1 as a workaround.

Comment: Thank you for your answerit removed the mentioned error but now it is telling me that the reference for jQuery in the "bootstrap-select.js" is not defined i am trying to solve this.

Comment: The above should be fixed now in the 0.32.3 release of react-bootstrap. If you are hitting a different issue now, maybe you can post it as a new question. bootstrap-select is a different component entirely.

Comment: Yes of course i will first try to solve it and if i can't i surely will. Thank you